# Any way to make a C# List with a number of elements?

Tags: c#, list

Any way to make a C# List with a given number of elements all at once? Not just add one by one, or copied from other IEnumerable. Then I can use indexers to assign values. I found a constructor `List(int capacity)`. Does it help?

Comment: Why not use array then?

Comment: I need some list features in the future.

Comment: Do you have predetermined values that you want the list to be created from?

Comment: I guess you want to achieve best performance by pre-allocate enough memory. If so, `List(int capacity)` did the trick.

Comment: By setting the capacity of `List` you're telling it to set the initial size of the array that it uses.  So if you never add more than that number it doesn't need to resize that array.  However it does not actually allow you to index those values until you add items to the list as it keeps an internal count that it uses to determine if indexes are out of bounds.  Why do you think you need this?  Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do we can give you a data structure or algorithm to solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can put it like this

```
 var List<MyType> result = Enumerable
   .Range(0, count)
   .Select(index => create your type instance here)
   .ToList();
```

and you may, probably, don't want additional steps (since you can fill the list via `Select`). If you're looking for *performance* then

```
 // new List<MyType>(count) reserves memory for "count" items 
 // so "Add" will not reallocate the list
 var List<MyType> result = new List<MyType>(count);

 for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
   result.Add(create your type instance here);
```

Comment: Or even `Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), count).ToList()`

Comment: I am wondering the performance. Does it first make a sequence and then copy it to a list? Or just directly work on the list?

Comment: @2kay: because of "...Then I can use indexers to assign values..." I prefer `Range(0, count)` and fill the list via `Select`

Comment: @user1899020: Linq adds a little *overhead* here, but I doubt it's a *significant* one. Technically, `List<MyType> result = new List<MyType>(int capacity); for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {...};` is faster.

Comment: Actually, Linq can add a LOT of overhead here for large lists, since it could resize the underlying buffer several times while making the list - because it won't know in advance how large the final list will be. Every time it increases the list's internal capacity (not the length), it copies all the data from the current internal buffer to a new internal buffer. That's pretty nasty.